# What does "A dream is, so to speak, an additional helping of experience for which, in my opinion, we are never sufficiently graceful." mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> A dream is, so to speak, an additional helping of experience for which, in my opinion, we are never sufficiently graceful.

As the title says, I can't figure out what the sentence means. I would appreciate it if you would answer my question.

Comment: Pleae provide the source for your quote.

Comment: Because this sentence is quoted from what a non-native speaker wrote on a website, it may contain some mistakes on words or grammar, and now I've figured out what the original sentence means, thanks to the people here.

Comment: Yes, it may contain some mistakes.  That is not a reason not to tell us the source of the quote.  You should always cite your source.  In this case I think the source is the book of "English text that Toshiya Echizen's Japanese will always mistranslate"  that https://inumimi.papy.co.jp/inmm/sc/kiji/1-1287561-84/  Which contains examples of hard to translate English.

Comment: Except you have miscoppied "grateful" as "graceful"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I think we are never sufficiently grateful for our dreams."

The sentence you quoted is a mess.  Question: to whom or to what should we be grateful?

Comment: I thought it was "graceful", not "grateful". You mean the right sentence is saying that "... sufficiently grateful", right?

Comment: Right! "Graceful" makes no sense.

Comment: Yes, they must have meant "grateful".  Using "grateful" like this can just mean being appreciative of something, without referring to anyone in particular, or they could mean being grateful to God.  It is not unusual to leave it ambiguous in everyday speech.